URGENT - Error Geometry Message with Newest version of Navigation2
I am using Docker containers to run the code on my robot. Recently, I had to add a package in my Dockerfile, and the image was rebuilt. I now have constantly an error on ros2 run that dissappear when removing navigation 2.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py", line 46, in import_type_support
    return importlib.import_module(module_name, package=pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1176, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/geometry_msgs_s__rosidl_typesupport_c.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: geometry_msgs__msg__velocity_stamped__convert_to_py

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xplore/dev_ws/install/rover_pkg/lib/rover_pkg/new_rover", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('rover-pkg==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'new_rover')())
  File "/home/xplore/dev_ws/install/rover_pkg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rover_pkg/new_rover.py", line 206, in main
    rover = RoverNode()
  File "/home/xplore/dev_ws/install/rover_pkg/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rover_pkg/new_rover.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.node.create_subscription(Odometry,         '/lio_sam/odom',                self.model.Nav.nav_odometry  , 10)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/install/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1367, in create_subscription
    check_is_valid_msg_type(msg_type)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/install/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/type_support.py", line 35, in check_is_valid_msg_type
    check_for_type_support(msg_type)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/install/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/type_support.py", line 29, in check_for_type_support
    msg_or_srv_type.__class__.__import_type_support__()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nav_msgs/msg/_odometry.py", line 47, in __import_type_support__
    PoseWithCovariance.__class__.__import_type_support__()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/msg/_pose_with_covariance.py", line 34, in __import_type_support__
    module = import_type_support('geometry_msgs')
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py", line 48, in import_type_support
    raise UnsupportedTypeSupport(pkg_name)
rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport: Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'geometry_msgs'
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

I tried to reinstall rosidl from source with an older version that works (as it was recently updated), but it now still gives me the problem.
Steps to reproduce:

Use docker Image ghcr.io/epflxplore/rover:humble-jetson
Create a simple package using a geometry msgs
Run the node

